# XSLT: Add line breaks before preserve space elements

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

This is my edited previous question for line breaks before the preserve space elements.

Suppose my xml like this,

```
<content>
<titleGroup>
<title>text</title>
</titleGroup>
<creators1>
<creator>
<personName>
  <Name>john</Name>
</personName>
</creator>
</creators1>
<creators2>
<affiliation>
<orgDiv> text </orgDiv>
<address>
<country>UK</country>
</address>
</affiliation>
</creators2>
</content>
```

i used the following xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:preserve-space elements ="creators1 creators2"/>

<xsl:template match ="/">
 <xsl:copy>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>    
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

output produced by this xml,

```
<content><titleGroup><title>text</title></titleGroup><creators1>
<creator><personName><Name>john</Name></personName></creator></creators1><creators2>
<affiliation><orgDiv>text</orgDiv><address><country>UK</country></address></affiliation></creators2></content>
```

but i need line breaks before the element in the elements list of preserve space not after that element (a tag need to start and end into a single line) like this,

```
 <content><titleGroup><title>text</title></titleGroup>
 <creators1><creator><personName><Name>john</Name></personName></creator></creators1>
<creators2><affiliation><orgDiv>text</orgDiv><address><country>UK</country></address></affiliation></creators2></content>
```

**i need to give a line break at the end of titlegroup and also at the end of creators1.**

pls don't suggest the answer like use `<xsl:text></xsl:text>` i need to do this by using preserve space or some other ways.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously it depends a lot on how you are processing it but with MSXSL 3 (which I assumed you were using from your namespaces), removing the output mode, getting rid of the preserve space and putting the text in the space

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

        <xsl:template match ="@* | node()">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>    
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="creators1 | creators2">
            <xsl:text>
            </xsl:text>
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
            </xsl:copy>  
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

gives you:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?><content><titleGroup><title>text</title></titleGroup>
    <creators1><creator><personName><Name>john</Name></personName></creator></creators1>
    <creators2><affiliation><orgDiv> text </orgDiv><address><country>UK</country></address></affiliation></creators2></content>
```

and something similar in Xalan and Saxon